# leafelt markercluster: open popup on childmarker after zoom in

Tags: javascript, popup, leaflet, markerclusterer, leaflet.markercluster

I have a leaflet map and using [Leaflet.markercluster](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster).
The data for the markers come from an external service as json.

After loading the map, the popups from all visible markers are open as I want.
But when i zoom out of the map the markers will be clustered and the popup disappear.
At this point all worked fine, but when I zoom in, I want to open the popup of each childmarker again without clicking the marker itself.

At the moment the code looks like this:

```
vehicleClusterMarkers = L.markerClusterGroup({
    maxClusterRadius: 45,
    spiderfyOnMaxZoom: false
});
vehicleClusterMarkers.addLayer(TTJsonLayer);

//vehicleClusterMarkers.addTo(map);
map.addLayer(vehicleClusterMarkers);

vehicleClusterMarkers.eachLayer(function(layer) {
    layer.openPopup();
});
```

I have done some research, but at the moment I have no idea how to solve this problem.

If anybody has some tips it would be nice.
Thx!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have several possible solutions to automatically open the popup of your unclustered Markers. You have to use event listeners, and you could listen to [`"zoomend"`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-zoomend), or probably better, to [`"layeradd"`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-layeradd) event (since Leaflet.markercluster also removes markers out of the view, so panning without changing the zoom level makes some new Markers appear).

Leaflet.markercluster plugin automatically removes your Markers from the map when they cluster, and add them back when they uncluster.

On `"layeradd"`, check if the added layer is an individual Marker (i.e. instance of class `L.Marker`), rather than a Cluster. If it is a single Marker, then open its popup:

```js
var map = L.map("map", {
  closePopupOnClick: false,
  maxZoom: 18
}).setView([48.85, 2.35], 11);

map.on('layeradd', function(event) {
  var layer = event.layer;

  if (layer instanceof L.Marker && !(layer instanceof L.MarkerCluster)) {
    layer.openPopup();
  }
});

var mcg = L.markerClusterGroup();

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i += 1) {
  L.marker(getRandomLatLng()).addTo(mcg).bindPopup('Marker ' + i, {
    autoClose: false,
    autoPan: false
  });
}

mcg.addTo(map);

L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);

function getRandomLatLng() {
  return [
    48.8 + 0.1 * Math.random(),
    2.25 + 0.2 * Math.random()
  ];
}
```

```html
<!-- Leaflet assets -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-Rksm5RenBEKSKFjgI3a41vrjkw4EVPlJ3+OiI65vTjIdo9brlAacEuKOiQ5OFh7cOI1bkDwLqdLw3Zg0cRJAAQ==" crossorigin="" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet-src.js" integrity="sha512-IkGU/uDhB9u9F8k+2OsA6XXoowIhOuQL1NTgNZHY1nkURnqEGlDZq3GsfmdJdKFe1k1zOc6YU2K7qY+hF9AodA==" crossorigin=""></script>

<!-- Leaflet.markercluster assets -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet.markercluster@1.3.0/dist/MarkerCluster.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet.markercluster@1.3.0/dist/MarkerCluster.Default.css">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet.markercluster@1.3.0/dist/leaflet.markercluster-src.js"></script>

<div id="map" style="height: 200px"></div>
```

Comment: thanks a lot and during the day I studied the leaflet documentation and thought perhaps event listener could solve my problem and this is correct.

Comment: one more question: how and is it possible to open the popup only on the clustermarker layer?
currently I have other layers which use also `L.marker` and after the `layeradd` is fired the popup of the last marker of the non clusterlayer is open.

Comment: and another question:
`map.on('layeradd')` works fine but, I have another `L.marker` on the map on every time a layer is added a popup on the wrong marker also appears.

I have tried different methods to exclude theL.marker for example with `.hasLayer()`, `L.featureGroup` or `L.stamp` to get the id and at the moment I am a little bit disapointed about the missing success.
has anybody an advice for me?

Comment: Please open a new question for your new issue, with relevant details and code.

Answer (score 1):

this is my solution after studying the documentation to solve the this problem. it also worked but opens allways all popups, even they are already opened and I don't know if this has negative consequences for the perfomance of the map.

```
map.on('zoomend', function() {
    vehicleClusterMarkers.eachLayer(function(layer) {
        layer.openPopup();
    });
});
```

Comment: Close all before you open them again.